# InstallESD.dmg in my Mac mini

Tags: mac, mac-mini, macos-ventura

My Mac mini 2018 has only 120 Gb of on-board storage. I was going through the storage management tool, and I found a 7.75 Gb file named InstallESD.dmg in this directory:

Drive / Users / (AcctName) / Library / Caches / com.apple.bird / unlink / (folder with a long name of letters and number) / InstallESD.dmg

FWIW, the other user account does not have the same file in the same directory:

Drive / Users / (OtherAcctName) / Library / Caches / com.apple.bird / unlink /   (empty)

And in the system library there's also nothing:

Drive / library / caches  does not have an analogous folder.

Seems like this can't be a critical system file if it's in a user folder, but am I wrong? Can I delete this?

Comment: It sounds like a system update that was downloaded but not installed. Go to Settings > General > Software Updates and see if you have any software updates waiting to be installed.

Comment: i wouldn't delete that. It's your mac's offline recovery installation media. So if you ever run into trouble, you can boot into recovery mode and re-install mac os using that.

Comment: @Mastaxx No, not on his main data volume it's not. The offline recovery medium is a separate mostly-hidden recovery partition that never gets mounted unless you boot into recovery mode. This disk image on his main data filesystem must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to /tmp/ and reboot. The file will be deleted by the very same System it was created ;o)

It took me years to realize this!